# Functon need to wait for result of other function

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm creating form which is using data of the current logged in user. Function which is setting value of form is done before getting user data.

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.auth.getUserState()
      .subscribe( user => {
        this.user = user;
      });
    this.resetForm();
  }

  resetForm(form?: NgForm) {
    if (form != null) { form.resetForm(); }
    this.service.formData = {
      who: this.user.email,
      id: null,
      name: '',
      content: '',
      date: null,
      done: false
    };
  }
```

How can i stop initialization of "resetForm" before component get current user data and complete "who" field with properly value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can place it inside the subscription of `getUserState()`:

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.auth.getUserState()
      .subscribe( user => {
        this.user = user;
        this.resetForm();
      });      
  }
```

Thereby, once the *user* information is present then only the `resetForm(...)` is called.